# Cannot manipulate Dataframe to calculate zscore using simple looping

Tags: python, pandas, loops, statistics

I'm following a Datacamp course on "efficient data manipulation" on pandas. On their videos, by way of example, they are demonstrating the native method of looping over the dataframe to calculate the zscore.

I have found this specific course strange with what seem to be errors in the code and I'm wondering if it was done for an older version of Python, but it is more likely just me not getting it.

The Dataframe is basically something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'total_bill': {0: 16.99, 1: 10.34, 2: 21.01, 3: 23.68, 4: 24.59, 5: 25.29, 6: 8.77, 7: 26.88, 8: 15.04, 9: 14.78}, 'tip': {0: 1.01, 1: 1.66, 2: 3.5, 3: 3.31, 4: 3.61, 5: 4.71, 6: 2.0, 7: 3.12, 8: 1.96, 9: 3.23}, 'sex': {0: 'Female', 1: 'Male', 2: 'Male', 3: 'Male', 4: 'Female', 5: 'Male', 6: 'Male', 7: 'Male', 8: 'Male', 9: 'Male'}, 'smoker': {0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: 'No', 3: 'No', 4: 'No', 5: 'No', 6: 'No', 7: 'No', 8: 'No', 9: 'No'}, 'day': {0: 'Sun', 1: 'Sun', 2: 'Sun', 3: 'Sun', 4: 'Sun', 5: 'Sun', 6: 'Sun', 7: 'Sun', 8: 'Sun', 9: 'Sun'}, 'time': {0: 'Dinner', 1: 'Dinner', 2: 'Dinner', 3: 'Dinner', 4: 'Dinner', 5: 'Dinner', 6: 'Dinner', 7: 'Dinner', 8: 'Dinner', 9: 'Dinner'}, 'size': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 4, 8: 2, 9: 2}})
```

So the code on the slides is as follows:

```
mean_female = df.groupby("sex").mean()["total_bill"]["Female"]
mean_male = df.groupby("sex").mean()["total_bill"]["Male"]
std_female = df.groupby("sex").std()["total_bill"]["Female"]
std_male = df.groupby("sex").std()["total_bill"]["Male"]
```

Followed by this...

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i,2] == "Female":
        df.iloc[i][0] = (df.iloc[i,0] - mean_female) / std_female
    else: 
        df.iloc[i][0] = (df.iloc[i,0] - mean_male) / std_male
```

When I run the code (which is from datacamp not mine) I get the usual copy of a slice warning, but (more importantly) NOTHING happens to the data frame.

I assume the objective is to have something like this:

```
zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
dfsex = restaurant.groupby('sex')
dfzscore = grouptime["total_bill"].transform(zscore)
dfzscore
```

I'm a little confused so any help figuring this out is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`.iloc[i,0]` should be used instead of `.iloc[i][0]`. The dataframe will be updated correctly after fixing this bug. Evidence:

```
df
Out[58]: 
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0   -0.707107  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1   -1.138059  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2    0.402209  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3    0.787637  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4    0.707107  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
5    1.020048  4.71    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     4
6   -1.364696  2.00    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
7    1.249573  3.12    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     4
8   -0.459590  1.96    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
9   -0.497122  3.23    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
```

**Explanation**: Let's take a close look at `df.iloc[i][0]`. The first step `df.iloc[i]` returns a Series in-place indeed. The second step `[0]`, however, just returns a copy of value which is not in-place. Therefore `df` won't be updated.

In short, every indice must be put inside `.iloc[]` (or arguably better `.iat[]` in this case) for the value assignment to happen in-place.

Comment: Thanks, putting the iloc [i,0] was the first thing I tried but clearly I didn't do it properly!

Should have checked my code before running to StackOverflow!!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
df.assign(column0_name= lambda x: np.where(x['column2_name']=='Female',
                       (x['column0_name'] - mean_female) / std_female),
                       (x['column0_name'] - mean_male) / std_male)))
```

Instead of:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i,2] == "Female":
        df.iloc[i][0] = (df.iloc[i,0] - mean_female) / std_female
    else: 
        df.iloc[i][0] = (df.iloc[i,0] - mean_male) / std_male
```

It works on series and works faster than for loop.